# Java: Possibility to insert many objects into one method with one parameter using one line of code

Tags: java

I was wondering if it is possible in JAVA to insert at the same type in one line many objects into a method, that accepts those types of objects. For example:

I have an object `Student`. Some instances of this object like:

```
student1, student2, student3
```

I have a method which accepts instances of Student: `addStudents(Student student);`

Currently I write something like this:

```
classRoom.addStudents(student1);
classRoom.addStudents(student2); 
classRoom.addStudents(student3); ...
```

Is it possible to create a method, which would accept the following code: `classRoom.addStudents(student1, student2, student3, etc);`

What steps could I use to start writing that method?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can use this notation:

```
private void addStudents(Student... students) {
    // your code here
}
```

It's called [varargs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/language/varargs.html), meaning variable number of arguments.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `...` in java to accept a number of variables with the same type. Here is quick example using `int`.

```
public static void main(String... args){ //You can also do it in main
    printNumbers(1);
    printNumbers(1,2,3);
}

public static void printNumbers(int... numbers){ //creates int[] numbers
    for (int i: numbers){
        System.out.println(i);
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

Output:

```
1

1
2
3
```

Answer (score 2):

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class ClassRoom {
    private List<Student> studentList = new ArrayList<>();

    public void addStudents(Student... students) {
        studentList.addAll(Arrays.asList(students));
    }
}
```

Sample student class

```
class Student {

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible ..**Make a Array of type student.. Put the object on that array. and pass the array as a argument of the insert method**. This process will only help you not to call the same method so many times. **In the method you can iterate the array and so your operations on the objects**.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to have variable parameter length with the following code:

```
public void addStudents(Student... students) {...}
```

`students` will be an array of `Student`.